# Using both SQLALCHEMY session and scoped_session with the same engine in FastAPI

Tags: python, database, multithreading, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using sqlalchemy with a FastAPI server and I came across the following error when I called `Session` object from a multithread function (not via http requests):

```
QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/3o7r)
```

This error only happens when my server is getting hundreds of requests and my thread workers are busy.

I read that `sqlalchemy.scoped_session` can be used for a background daemon.

Doing the following made the error disappear:

1. Regular sqlalchemy `Session` object in the http requests, via `FastAPI.Depends()` just like it is recommend in the docs
2. sqlalcehmy `scoped_session` - My server is running tasks in the background in different threads which need access to the database but each thread **has its own session**

Safe to say that each session object is being handled appropriately (`scoped_session` calls `remove()` and `Session` calls `close()`)

My question is - is it not recommended using this approach when i'm using **a single engine**? Should I take a different path?

Thanks!